# Cloud Run authentication to run job in GKE cluster

Tags: java, authentication, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

When running the following code locally I can create a job in a GKE cluster:

```
  final ConfigBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder();
    if (args.length > 0) {
      configBuilder.withMasterUrl(args[0]);
    }
    try (KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(configBuilder.build()).build()) {
      final String namespace = "default";
      final Job job = new JobBuilder()
          .withApiVersion("batch/v1")
          .withNewMetadata()
          .withName("pi")
          .withLabels(Collections.singletonMap("label1", "maximum-length-of-63-characters"))
          .withAnnotations(Collections.singletonMap("annotation1", "some-very-long-annotation"))
          .endMetadata()
          .withNewSpec()
          .withNewTemplate()
          .withNewSpec()
          .addNewContainer()
          .withName("pi")
          .withImage("perl:5.34.0")
          .withArgs("perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)")
          .endContainer()
          .withRestartPolicy("Never")
          .endSpec()
          .endTemplate()
          .endSpec()
          .build();

      logger.info("Creating job pi.");
      client.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace).createOrReplace(job);

      // Print Job's log

      PodList podList = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("job-name", job.getMetadata().getName()).list();
      client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withName(podList.getItems().get(0).getMetadata().getName());

      String joblog = client.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace).withName("pi").getLog();
      logger.info(joblog);

    } catch (KubernetesClientException e) {
      logger.error("Unable to create job", e);
    }
  }
```

Now I want to do the same from cloud run. In order to do that I used the following Dockerfile to create an image:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/cloud-run-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar ./cloud-run-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar
CMD java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar cloud-run-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar
```

Once I had created the image I pushed it to the artifact registry by doing this:

```
docker push southamerica-east1-docker.pkg.dev/kubernetes-hello-world-360615/hello-repo/cloud-run:v1
```

I can see the image in the registry, and I could try and run the job. The result was the following:

```
2022-08-30T20:35:56.946572Zio.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred. at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:103) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:97) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:44) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.internal.CreateOrReplaceHelper.createOrReplace(CreateOrReplaceHelper.java:50) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:296) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:88) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:1036) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.createOrReplace(BaseOperation.java:88) at kubernetes.example.Main.main(Main.java:49) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Name or service not known at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1529) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1519) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1378) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306) at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:215) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:66) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:66) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientBuilderImpl$InteceptorAdapter.intercept(OkHttpClientBuilderImpl.java:66) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I think the most interesting part of the logs is this one: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Name or service not known

This was to be expected since the java code doesn't know how to authenticate against the EKS cluster. Now the logs show some interesting attempts by the library to configure the client:

```
Trying to configure client from Kubernetes config...
```

```
Did not find Kubernetes config at: [/home/.kube/config]. Ignoring.
```

```
Trying to configure client from service account...
```

```
Did not find service account ca cert at: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt}].
```

```
Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring.
```

```
Trying to configure client namespace from Kubernetes service account namespace path...
```

```
 Did not find service account namespace at: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace]. Ignoring.
```

Now the question is: How to configure a kubernetes client running in Cloud Run to connect to a GKE cluster? I think maybe the service account part of the logs means that attaching a service account to Cloud Run might help with authentication.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've not fully read your question (apolz) but I'm familiar with connecting to Kubernetes clusters from other services. Generally (!) the approach w/ GKE is to use the Google Container (Kubernetes) service to e.g. [`projects.locations.clusters.get`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/get) and use the [`Cluster`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster) resource to construct a Kubernetes `v1.Config`.

Comment: Here's a [sample](https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/9506c0b9677d53a3e11b7457ed21cbe7) using Golang that you can hopefully grok to write the equivalent Java.